# Convert Strings to Class Names in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a script in ruby which involves converting a string to Class Names. Since I am using pure ruby I cannot use `.constantize`.
I have tried using `Object.const_get('String')` but not sure why it is throwing a  `uninitialized constant String (NameError)`

I have `require 'active_support'` on the top of the file

Comment: Would you mind to try `Kernel.const_get 'String'`?

Comment: can you say any info about your ruby version / platform? `Object.const_get('String')` works for me.

Comment: @mudasobwa I tried that as well. But I got 
**uninitialized constant Kernel::String (NameError)**

Comment: @maxpleaner That's working for me in the rails console but when I put that in the script it's not working.
I am using ruby 2.4.4

Comment: For me both ways work on `ruby 2.4.1p111`. No need to require anything.

Comment: @iGian are you trying in the rails console? 
I am trying to execute that from a ruby file

Comment: Just to clarify, are you literally passing in a string value of 'String', or arbitrary strings ('foo', 'Bar','Number')?  The latter will return a NameError, typically either 'uninitialized constant' or 'wrong constant name', unless the name is an exact class name.

Comment: @daryn This is what I am doing from inside a ruby script.
**Object.const_get('Assignment')** 
This is throwing me an error.

Comment: @Robin for me works in Rails Terminal and in Ruby script

Comment: @Robin is the `Assignment` class actually loaded at the time of the call?( e.g. via `require 'assigments'` ) `Module#const_get` will require such a thing as it will not "autoload" undeclared constants the way rails does

Comment: Additionally since you are requiring `ActiveSupport` you can use the constantize method via `ActiveSupport::Inflector.constantize("String")` or by addition `require 'active_support/core_ext/string'` after `require 'active_support'` and then `"String".constantize` or even `"string".classify.constantize` will work for you

Answer (score 3):

The conventional way of assigning a name to an anonymous class is as follows.

```
bub = Class.new do
  def b
    'hi'
  end
end

str = 'Bubba'
Object.const_set(str, bub)

Bubba.is_a?(Class)
  #=> true
Bubba.new.b
  #=> "hi"
```

Is that what you want to do? If so, as you see, you need to use [Module#const_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set).

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to use `const_get` only for a class or it is under a namespace like `ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassName`?

Also converting a string to a class name makes a new class or assigns the value to it?

I am asking these questions because the answer will affect the method you have to use. Maybe `const_set` instead of `const_get` is the correct approach, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you gave it looks like `'String'` is just an example and not the value that you literally pass to `const_get`. The actual value apparently is 'Assignment', is this correct?

When you execute `Object.const_get('Assignment')` and you receive the `uninitialized constant` error it indicates that at this point the class `Assignment` has not been loaded yet.

When you are using `Rails` then a lot of autoloading takes place if the files are in the right folder and the classes follow the naming conventions. Since you are running a "standalone" ruby script,  autoloading does not take place and you will need to load the file yourself.

Adding a line like

`require_relative "somepath/assignment"`

should work. `somepath` needs to be adapted to the directory/file layout you have. It will load the file and execute the ruby code in that file.
If `assignment.rb` defines something like

```
class Assignment
end
```

Then the `const_get` will work.

That being said: what is your exact use case for this? Why do you need to dynamically find classes? Also Note that this opens up your app to (an unlikely) potential security issues if you let user input define what classes are loaded.